# A style for a datagridviewcell is applied but not visible

Tags: wpf, datagridviewcellstyle

I made a template for a cell in a column of a wpf datagrid.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="R" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Width="10" Height="10" BorderThickness="3">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
                <Rectangle Width="7" Height="7" Fill="Red"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Wpf inspector shows that the style is applied, but it is not visible. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `it is not visible` you mean that you don't see the border around your `Rectangle` then it's because you didn't set [Border.BorderBrush property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.borderbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If changed like this, you'll see black border around your red Rectangle:

```
<Border Width="10" Height="10" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black">
```

Green background you won't see because it is under `Rectangle`.

Comment: @Gerard, it becomes a habit to always think about Thickness and Brush properties together. Before that it's easy to miss one of the two =)